# Can a bug in a Python library produce a ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python

I have to run a simple code snippet which uses the [mexc_sdk](https://pypi.org/project/mexc-sdk/0.0.1/#description) library. I installed it properly, it is in the proper folder, but somehow I get the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mexc_sdk'` message when I run the below code. (Visual Studio throws an `Import "mexc_sdk" could not be resolved` warning as well.)

```
from mexc_sdk.src.mexc_sdk import Spot

client = Spot()

info = client.exchange_info(options={ "symbol": "BTCUSDT"})

print(info)
```

I already installed it on my server which is Linux while my PC is a Windows machine with different setup and I get the same error there. So I have no idea what can be the problem. My Python version is 3.8 and the lib is compatible from 3.6.

I also checked the folder of the installed lib and it doesn't contain any Python files, but as I am not familiar with libraries I don't know if it's normal or not. My question is, how should I debug this? Is it possible that the library is not installed correctly?

Comment: Go open up your Python installation's `site-packages` directory (or the `~/.local` or virtual environment equivalent if applicable) and verify that there is in fact a file of the form `site-packages/mexc_sdk/src/mexc_sdk/__init__.py` or `site-packages/mexc_sdk/src/mexc_sdk.py`? If there isn't, correct your import.

Comment: @ShadowRanger the problem is I can't find any src folder or Python files at all. Seems like the installation is wrong, but there is github link in the metadata file.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs you are importing it wrong

```
from mexc_sdk import Spot
spot = Spot(api_key='apiKey', apiSecret='apiSecret')
```

Assuming you installed it correctly.

Comment: Tried this as well with the same result. In the example files they use the other import type. But unfortunately doesnt matter

Comment: Are you doing pip install or downloading the repo?

Comment: Also are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: I am using pip install.